# restrict users from accessing other user profiles

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have to implement security on my app by preventing users to access other users profile.

**route.js**

```
router.get('/currentUser/:username', userAuth, (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    username: req.params.username
  }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(200).json(user);
    } else {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: 'User not found'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

and my **userAuth.js**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    jwt.verify(token, 'app_secret_token');
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({
      message: 'Authentication failed!'
    });
  }
};
```

now if I am logged in as user **test** so my URL will be http://localhost:4200/currentuser/test but if I change my URL to another user **test2** it redirects and loads the test2 even though I am logged as test

how do I prevent this?

Comment: Simplest solution - Have a `/currentUser` or better `/user/me` route which will parse the cookies or token and return the decoded user.

Answer (score 3):

You need to also check that the logged in user accesses his data.

you can achieve this by checking the user in the token against the requested page. This means you need to encode the user Id inside the jwt token. That will also make sure this parameter wasn't meddled with since `jwt.verify` would fail if someone tried to change the jwt token without having the secret.

you can add that data to the jwt token when signing it:

```js
jwt.sign({
  userId: 'username'
}, 'secret', { expiresIn: '1h' });
```

Basically if you save the same data as serializeUser\deserializeUser result, it should also work (the username is just a suggestion).

you can use the callback from `jwt.verify` to get the decoded token and retrieve that data

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    jwt.verify(token, 'app_secret_token', (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) { throw err; }

      const currentUsername = decoded.userId; // <-- this should be whatever data you encoded into the jwt token

      // if the user requested is different than the user in the token,
      // throw an authentication failure
      if (req.originalUrl.includes('/currentUser/') &&
          !req.originalUrl.includes(`/currentUser/${currentUsername}`)) {
        throw new Error('access to other user data denied');
       }

       next();
    });

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({
      message: 'Authentication failed!'
    });
  }
};
```

Even though I think this might be a good case separating this into two different middlewares :-)

PS - as @anand-undavia mentioned, it might be better to identify the user request based on the jwt token itself instead of the 'url' itself. that way, each user should *only have access to their own data* and this problem can't occur at all.

basically, the user should be accessible with the method above (getting it from the token) or from a `req.user` field if you use any middleware that adds it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

let us assume that user profile page id `mydomian?passedId=userId` so simply add `profile-guard` to check who can visit or activate this page, in `CanActivate` check if passed id id the same of current user id, then `return true` else redirect him to previous page

```
canActivate(
next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
let passedId: string = next.queryParams.passedId;
  let user = this.authService.GetUser();
  if (user.id == passedId)
    return true;
  else {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']); // or any page like un authorized to log to this page
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I know you gave an angular answer, but I'm not sure the angular tag has a meaning here. This question talks about the server side and not the client side code.

Comment: yeah but actually implement this idea mean in client side,I don't think handle such this authorization is true only in server side, we can handle it in client side also, so both are work fine @Thatkookooguy

Comment: That's not true. you can't only secure the url in the client. that means that the data is not secure and can be accessed if you just call the api to the server and go over the client altogether.

You have to secure the sensitive data from being sent without an the correct authenticated user.

Comment: Also, the original OP published the server side code, not the client side code. So I'm not sure this is actually related to the question itself as it was described.

Comment: so we need more explanation from post owner

Comment: yes. but my comment is still valid :-) you can't solve this on the client side without any changes in the server side for security reasons. Didn't mean anything but trying to help you improve your answer by these comments.

Comment: So we should send checkPermission to api and depending on response allow navigate or not, so in CanActivate just adding call checkAccess, is this What you mean?

Comment: I'm saying that you need to secure your API as well as your frontend. so let's say we have a `myserver.com/activeUser` GET endpoint that returns the user in JSON format. if that endpoint doesn't have proper authentication, and you check that the correct user is logged in in the UI (let's say `myserver.com/ui/activeUser`), I can still get the sensitive data and bypass your `canActivate` by simply calling `myserver.com/activeUser` to the server directly and not going through the UI. You should put guards on sensitive routes but it's not instead of server security

Comment: @Thatkookooguy I am using angular on my frontend that's why I added angular tag

Comment: @MuhammadAli unless your question is **actually related** to angular, you shouldn't add tags based on code that doesn't affect your problem. So I understand you frontend uses angular, but unless you post angular code here or ask for changes in the ui code, that tag is unrelated.